HP Elitebook g1 840 BIOS EFI issues
I've formatted my HP and reset the BIOS, and I have created a USB boot disk from a MAC. Now when I try to start the HP it doesn't find the EFI file. I've tried an external HDD as well, but that didn't work either so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I've asked for help on other forums but nothing works..
Please help.


Pls give more info, what is on your USB? What do you want to do?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
